# Referencing an array value in PHP

Tags: php

I am tring to program in drupal, but this is basically a php question:
If I have the following array structure:

```
$node = 'field_slot_11_1' => 
array (
0 => 
array (
  'value' => 'sdaad',
),
),
```

how do I reference the value? I have tried $node->field_slot_11_1[0]['value'] but it doesn't work.

Comment: That structure isn't particularly helpful, what does [`var_dump()`](http://php.net/var_dump) or [`var_export()`](http://php.net/var_export) say? If it's an array, why access it with object syntax?

Comment: That syntax is invalid. Do you mean `$node = array('field...' =>)`.

Comment: That throws a parse error. Either that is the problem (and you need to read your error messages) or you aren't showing us representative code.

Comment: I was just giving a snippet of the array. The realy array is much more complicated, its an array that drupal created for me.

Comment: Please don't only provide half a question; we might only provide half an answer.

Answer (score 5):

Use this instead:

```
$node = array(
    'field_slot_11_1' => array(
        0 => array(
            'value' => 'sdaad',
        ),
    ),
)
...
$node['field_slot_11_1'][0]['value']
```

Comment: Is there a reason my answer was downvoted?

Comment: Yes; you assumed that `$node` was an array.

Comment: When answering, please make sure you give proper indented code for maximum readability.

Answer (score 4):

Your syntax is a bit off. Correcting for that:

```
<?php
  $node = array( 'field_slot_11_1' => array ( 0 => array ( 'value' => 'sdaad' ) ) );
  echo $node[ 'field_slot_11_1' ][ 0 ][ 'value' ];
?>
```

Comment: +1 for the statement about invalid syntax.

Answer (score 0):

You $node variable is ill formatted. It is neither a proper object nor a proper array. If you make it an array like this:

```
$node = array('field_slot_11_1' => 
    array (0 => 
        array ('value' => 'sdaad',
        ),
    ),
);
```

Then you can refer to it like:

```
$node['field_slot_11_1'][0]['value'];
```